# How to mod rewrite domain but keep evertything after the domain intact

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two different domains. Lets call them domain1 and domain2.

I need to mod rewrite:

www.domain1.com/some/stuff/after-domain

so that it becomes:

www.domain2.com/some/stuff/after-domain

Basically, everything after the domain should remain the same. The only difference should be changing the domain names. Can anyone help me with the rewrite rules for this. I've tried the following, but it's not working for me.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain2.com$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Also, please note, that {REQUEST_URI} and {REQUEST_FILENAME} will not work for this application.

Thank you in advance, as always.

EDIT:
Per the request for more info, the result I get when using the rule above:
http://www.domain1.comhttp//www.domain1.com/some/stuff/after-domain

Additionally, I forgot to specify that I'd like the domain1 to appear in the address bar URL, but pull content based on domain2 (is this even possible?)

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Does it give an error? Does it just not do anything? Is `AllowOverride` enabled in apache config? Need more info.

Comment: Updated per your request

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed a general case where you want to redirect everything to one domain, so that you don't need to specify every possible permutation:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain1.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain1.com$1
```

That should achieve what I think you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, your solution misses a "/" between the .com and the some/stuff/after-domain. Also, I forgot to specify that I'd like the domain1 to appear in the address bar URL, but pull content based on domain2.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 / http://www.domain2.com/
```

It should redirect: `www.domain1.com/some/stuff/after-domain` -> `www.domain2.com/some/stuff/after-domain`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, I didn't specify that I wanted domain1 to remain in the address bar.

Comment: Can you try it again (you might need to do a hard fresh). It changes the url for me to the new domain

Comment: Yes, sorry, I want the old domain url to remain in the address bar. But load content based on the new domain.

Comment: As far as I am aware, that can't be done with htaccess. You could use an iframe, but the url will only show `www.domain1.com` no matter what page you visit on `www.domain2.com`